# Unity Kin plugin - bad request

Tags: unity-game-engine, kin

I am writing code to connect Unity to the Kin blockchain. However, calling Addaccount() just returns a null (no error).

To further test, I used the KinDemoScene that comes with the plugin, unmodified, and tried to create an account. This also fails with the error:

[image: Bad Request KinDemo]

I have checked my firewall, and also compiled the phone and run it on an android phone, with the same result.

So both my code and the KinDemoScene are failing. What am I doing wrong?

Below is my code: ([kin-sdk-android:1.0.2](https://github.com/kinecosystem/kin-sdk-unity) and [Kin SDK for Unity version 1.0](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/kin-sdk-for-unity-android-beta-137182))

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Kin;

public class KinConnector : MonoBehaviour
{
    private KinClient kinClient;
    private KinAccount account;

    void Start()
    {
        kinClient = new KinClient(Environment.Test, "test");
        try
        {
            if (!kinClient.HasAccount())
            {
                account = kinClient.AddAccount();
                //**NO ERROR RETURNED, JUST A NULL****
            }
            else
            {
                account = kinClient.GetAccount(0);
            }
        }
        catch (KinException e)
        {
            Debug.LogError(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: is the `appId` correct?

Comment: @derHugo I'm using the exact, same appId in their demo app - which also isn't working... When I download the unity plugin, am I also supposed to separately download android sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiling:

1. Go to player settings and in Publishing Settings - click on "Custom Gradle Template"
2. Edit this template as per instructions in the Unity Plugin
3. Add Using Kin line to the top of your script
4. Under player settings, make sure 'minify' (Proguard) is disabled
5. Compile and test in your android device or emulator

**Running it on the unity editor will not work**